# Nodeclipse won't run or debug app on OSX Maverick, nodeclipse 0.8.0, and JDK 1.7.03_45

Tags: eclipse, node.js, nodeclipse

When I try to run or debug a nodejs app I get and error:

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "node" (in directory 
"/Users/<USERNAME>/Documents/Projects/<PROJECTNAME>"): error=2, No such file or directory.
```

I can run the app just fine in the the terminal.

My system is OSX Maverick, Eclipse Standard/SDK Version: Kepler Service Release 1
Build id: 20130919-0819, Nodeclipse 0.8.0, jdk1.7.0_45.jdk

Not sure if this is a bug or a configuration error.  I would like to know how to fix this.

Comment: Also asked as issue https://github.com/Nodeclipse/nodeclipse-1/issues/97

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should self solved problem, as it is clear that node can't be found so need to check current configuration Window -> Preferences -> Nodeclipse

```
Disable Find node on PATH,
then select node exact location, e.g. on Windows C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe
```

check Preferences carefully, experiment a bit.